# Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation using Quasar Framework

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I am using the Quasar Framework on a Vue3 application.

I have "successfully" integrated the `<q-slider />` component. However, upon panning the knob on the component, the following message gets logged on the console.

`Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation`

Efforts to resolve the issue have pointed me towards the browser with a common css solution being `style="touch-action: pan-x;"` but this does not work for me.

I have tested this on;

- Chrome: issue exists,
- Edge: issue exists,
- Firefox: issue exists
- Safari: issue DOES NOT exist.

My Quasar versions are:

- "@quasar/extras": "^1.16.9",
- "quasar": "^2.15.1",
- "@quasar/app-vite": "^1.8.0",

Edit: Code snippet

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'
import { sumBy } from 'lodash'

const strategy = ref([
  { label: 'Needs', color: 'primary', value: 50 },
  { label: 'Wants', color: 'negative', value: 29 },
  { label: 'Savings', color: 'positive', value: 20 },
])

const balance = computed(() => 100 - sumBy(strategy.value, 'value'))
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div
      v-for="item, index in strategy"
      :key="`strategy-item-${index}`"
    >
      <div class="row text-caption">
        <span class="text-body2">
          {{ item.label }}
        </span>
        <q-space></q-space>
        {{ item.value }}%
      </div>
      <q-slider
        snap
        :step="5"
        :max="100"
        :color="item.color"
        v-model="item.value"
        :inner-max="item.value + balance"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I guess you aren't adding an event listener `.addEventListener` anywhere?

Comment: @JaromandaX No I am not. Quasar components are more or less plug-n-play in nature and that kind of code is abstracted.

Answer (score 0):

As per script, there are some solutions for that you can try one of them hope it will works in your case

1. Add `{passive:false}` :

   - Find the event listener that is causing the violation to trigger. and add `{passive:false}` as a third argument ([source](https://www.uriports.com/blog/easy-fix-for-unable-to-preventdefault-inside-passive-event-listener/))

```js
   window.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
        // some logic
   }, {passive:false});
```

2. Add `touch-action: none;` css :

   - If you call preventDefault on touchstart then you should also have a CSS rule to disable touch scrolling like

Thank you

Comment: 1. The CSS option does not work.
2. I cannot access the eventListener since quasar is a material framework that abstracts this functionality.

Comment: try {passive:false} also one more option 
`event.cancelable && event.preventDefault()`

Comment: sadly, I do not have access to that code. This is abstracted at the library/framework level.

Comment: can you share the block of code? It will help to resolve.

Comment: Yeah. Sure thing. I've made an edit on the original post.

Comment: Hey, I Test Your Code in local and sandbox also but it didn't give such types of error. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/test-stackoverflow-zg2yj9

Comment: Hey i_am_prince. I truly do appreciate the help. 

I think it might be browser related. I am not sure which engine the sandbox runs on because when I use safari, I don't see the error. Only happens on chrome and edge.